# Using different S3 buckets for production and development in Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip, carrierwave

I'm starting to play around with [Carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave), as an alternative to [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

I can see from the documentation that to use S3 I should configure Fog in a initializer:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',       # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'xxx',       # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'yyy',       # required
    :region                 => 'eu-west-1'  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }

end
```

However, how do I set up different buckets for different environments? With paperclip I would specify different credentials and/or buckets for development/production/etc in a yml file. What is the best way to do that with carrierwave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it pretty much exactly the same way if you want, like this entirely untested idea:

```
# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  my_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/fog_credentials.yml"

  YAML.load_file(my_config)[Rails.env].each do |key, val|
    config.send("#{key}=", val)
  end
end

# config/fog_credentials.yml
common: &common
  aws_access_key: 'whatever'
  ...
  fog_credentials:
    provider: 'whoever'
    ...
production:
  <<: *common
  fog_directory: 'my-production-bucket'
development:
  <<: *common
  fog_directory: 'my-dev-bucket'
```

Or if you want to forego the YAML, you could always simply test for the environment in the initializer and use a case or conditional, at the simplest something like:

```
CarrierWave.configure.do |config|
  if Rails.env.development?
    # configure one env
  else
    # configure another
  end

  # configure common stuff
end
```

Comment: I haven't tested loading the YAML file as you suggested, but I'm going to go with option 2 and use a simple conditional statement. Looks good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
class S3ArticleUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  if Rails.env.test?
    storage :file
  else
    storage :fog
  end

  def fog_directory
    ARTICLE_UPLOADER_BUCKET
  end

  def store_dir
    "#{ model.parent_id }/#{ model.id }"
  end

end

# config/environments/development.rb
ARTICLE_UPLOADER_BUCKET = 'development-articles'

# config/environments/production.rb
ARTICLE_UPLOADER_BUCKET = 'production-articles'
```

fog_directory method calls when you are not in TestEnvironment and initializes the right 
BUCKET.

you can also do like this:

```
  def store_dir
    if self._storage == CarrierWave::Storage::File
      "#{Rails.root}/tmp/files/#{ model.parent_id }/#{ model.id }"
    elsif self._storage == CarrierWave::Storage::Fog
      "#{ model.parent_id }/#{ model.id }"
    end
  end
```

## v2

```
class S3ArticleUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  if Rails.env.test?
    storage :file
  else
    storage :fog
  end

  def initialize
    self.fog_directory = ARTICLE_UPLOADER_BUCKET
  end

  def store_dir
    "#{ model.parent_id }/#{ model.id }"
  end

end
```